# WPF Transparency and Switching Styles between Transparent and Non-Transparent

Tags: c#, wpf

2 Questions :

1. Firstly:
   Is it possible to Toggle Transparency on a WPF window? Any pointers greatly appreciated!
2. Secondly:
   Most controls on my window inherit their Transparancy from the parent window, however I have a Datagrid control with its own style - The style is in an external file that I reference (Style="{DynamicResource MyDGStyle}")..... in the xaml code behind can I switch Styles? (Ideally I would achieve this using a Style Trigger, but don't think I can).

Thanks very much

Joe

**Edit** (can't seem to reply)

Thanks alex, NVM

Regarding the Toggling Transparency, as long as I can set the 'Background' property of the Window at runtime from a color to 'Transparent' at that runtime, thats fine.

Regarding switching styles, just extending your code alex, presumably I can do something like

```
void OnButtonPress()
{
     var transparentStyle = Themes.CurrentTheme.MyDGNonTransparentStyle;
     var nonTransparentStyle = Themes.CurrentTheme.MyDGNonTransparentStyle;

     if (isTransparent) // Change to Non-Transparent
         this.MyGrid.Style = (Style)this.FindResource(nonTransparentStyle); 
     else // Change to Transparent
         this.MyGrid.Style = (Style)this.FindResource(nonTransparentStyle); 
}
```

?

Thanks

Joe

**3rd Edit**

Thanks guys,

Sorry to confuse you - my second question was since my datagrid has its own style (and doesn't inherit from the window) I will need to set its style depending on the current state (Transparent / Non-ransparent) - so I need to change the datagrid style at runtime - now since this can be done with a window, can I assume it can be done with a datagrid?

Thanks

Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is it possible to Toggle Transparency on a WPF window?*

Yes, it is:

```
<Window WindowStyle="None" 
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        Background="#88aa3366">
</Window/>
```

The bad news is that you have to implement the logic of window header by yourself. 
[This article](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2007/06/20/transparent-windows-in-wpf-2/) might be helpfull.

> *in the xaml code behind can I switch Styles?*

The question is a little bit unclear, maybe this helps:

```
var key = Themes.CurrentTheme.MyDGStyle;
this.MyGrid.Style = (Style)this.FindResource(key);
```

Comment: I don't think you can change AllowsTransparency at runtime.

Comment: Yes, but you could vary alpha channel by changing Background property: this.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,255,255,255)) // non transparent white background

Comment: Actually Joe.Net asked 2 questions. The first one is about transparent window. The answer is: when you set up AllowTransparency,  you are able to change window transparency by setting different alpha channel in Window.Background property. The second question I didn't understand too.